# How to combine multiple CSV files to one ods file on the command line. One sheet per original file

Tags: bash, csv

How to combine multiple CSV files to one ods file, **one sheet per file**.  I have ten CSV files and I would like to combine them to one ods file comprised of ten sheets, one per original CSV. This should be done on the command line.

Comment: I was recently playing with the perl module [Spreadsheet::Write](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Write), if you're into perl. Doing a little searching, I see a forked module [Spreadsheet::Wright](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Wright) which is more explicit about being able to write to OpenDocument XML format.

Comment: Hmm, it seems Spreadsheet::Wright is pretty buggy. I'd go with Spreadsheet::Write to create an XLSX file, and libreoffice can open that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
# CPAN modules required:
use Spreadsheet::Write;
use Text::CSV;

my $xlsx_file = shift @ARGV;
$xlsx_file .= ".xlsx" unless $xlsx_file =~ /\.xlsx$/;
my $xlsx = Spreadsheet::Write->new(file => $xlsx_file);
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1});

for my $csv_file (@ARGV) {
    my @rows = ();
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $csv_file;
    while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
        push @rows, $row;
    }
    $csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
    close $fh;  

    (my $sheet_name = $csv_file) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;   # strip extension
    $xlsx->addsheet($sheet_name);
    $xlsx->addrows(@rows);
}
$xlsx->close();
```

And use it like:

```
/path/to/create_xlsx.pl file.xlsx *.csv
```

If perl is not your thing, a bit of googling reveals:

- python: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- ruby: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644341/which-gem-support-import-export-to-xlsx-file-in-ruby

Comment: Thank you. I do not know perl (or python or rubby for that matter), but it seems you have done all the work for me :-). I just piped it through libreoffice --headless to get my .ods.

Comment: can you please explain "piped it through libreoffice --headless" for newbies as I am

Comment: ... and another question: does this approach work on Ubuntu?

Comment: @meolic Piped it through libreoffice headless means I used libreoffice -headless to convert the resulting xlsx into ods. And yes, it works in Ubuntu. Next time when you reply on a comment ping the respective user because we receive no notifications otherwise.